# get value from data that depend on other data

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to get the l input which will be between 0,1. the l input will be for A column. and second input will be the 'mesafe' column so the result must be 23 which is for A and mesafe's zero column. I get some error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def var():
    df = pd.read_csv('l_y.txt')
    l=float(input("speed of the wind:"))
    w=int(input("range:"))
    for l in range(0, 1) and w in range(0, 100) :
        print(df['A'].values[0])




l_y.txt=(  mesafe      A     B     C     D     E     F
       0     100     23    18    14     8     4     0
       1    1000    210   170   110    60    40    30
       2    5000    820   510   380   300   230   160
       3   10000   1600  1200   820   560   400   250
       4   20000   2800  2100  1600  1000   820   500
       5   50000   5900  4600  3400  3200  1600  1100
       6  100000  10000  8100  6100  3900  2800  2000 )    






Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    var()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\ml.py", line 
8, in var
    for l in range(0, 1) and w in range(0, 100) :
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I think you may want to try nesting one for loop inside of the other.

Comment: i tried it gives: key error 'A'

Comment: I am really sorry about my bad english. Yes, like you said l_y give depend on what is user input. i have a formula and in this formula there is a variable which depend on the speed of the wind and the range, the 'mesafe' mean is range and other columns are the speed,'s range which have value like 0-1, 1-5, 5-12...

Comment: So for each value of speed of wind and range there is a special value l_y. I hope you understand

Comment: Ok, I think I begin to understand. But if the mapping of l to the letters A...F is not 0, 1, 2 ...6 but 0-1, 1-5, 5-12... we need to know the rest of this list

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the format of the language. In this case if you want to run a double loop with `l` and `w`:

```
for l in range(0, 1):
    for w in range(0, 100) :
        print(df['A'].values[0])
```

Note the indent, if you don't indent properly then the python codes won't work correctly.

Also your code here doesn't seem to accomplish anything except printing the same thing for 200 times. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the output of this code will be used in determination of strontium-90 in a nuclear power reactor accident . in physics there is a lot of factor so that data is one of these factor i want to get the value depend on the other columns values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume you want to get a certain value from your matrix, depending on two input values l and w, so that if l is between 0 and 1 column 'A' should be selected. (I further assume, that if l is between 1 nd 2 it's column 'B', 2 <= l < 3 -> 'c', and so on...)
The row is directly derived from w with the data in the mesafe-column: if w is between 0 and 100 -> row 0, between 100 and 1000 -> row 1 and so on...

Well, this can be achieved as follows:

```
l = .3   # let's say user types 0.3
```

There is some mapping between l and the letters:

```
l_mapping = [1, 5, 12, 20, 35, 50]    # These are the thresholds between the columns A...F

l_index = np.searchsorted(l_mapping, l)   # calculate the index of the column letter

col = df.columns[1:][l_index]    # this translates l to the column names from A...F

col     # look what col is when l was < 1
Out: 'A'

w = 42   # now the user Input for w is 42

row = np.searchsorted(df.mesafe.values, w)   # this calculates the fractional index of w in df.mesafe

row
Out: 0
```

So with these two formulas you get column and row Information to index your desired result:

```
df[col].iloc[row]
Out: 23
```

Summing this all up in a function would look like this:

```
def get_l_y(l, w, df_ly):
    l_mapping = [1, 5, 12, 20, 35, 50]
    l_index = np.searchsorted(l_mapping, l)
    col = df_ly.columns[1:][l_index]
    row = np.searchsorted(df.mesafe.values, w)
    print(l, w, col, row)    # print Input and calculated row- and column- values for testing purpose, can be deleted/commented out if everything works as you want 
    return df[col].iloc[row]
```

This function expects l, w and the pandas-dataframe of your matrix as input Parameters and returns l_y.